# Date sorting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have merged 2 dataframes into one called 'DRG', this dataframe consists of how many times the term 'new detection' or 'pp reviewed' appeared within a certain day and it has a count beside each date. When I merged the tables the dates for 'new detection' and the dates for 'pp reviewed' won't match up because 'pp reviewed' occurs on less dates. How can I make just one date column with the count for 'new detections' and 'pp reviewed' matching up?

My goal is to plot a line graph with the date as the X axis and 'detection' and 'pp reviewed' as 2 different lines.

Please see below the DRG table,

[image]

Comment: I believe you'll have to use the dates from each of the individual dataframes as the keys, and then merge based on this key.

Comment: if you could provide a sample dataframe instead of a screenshot, this would help us to help you

Comment: Also can you provide an expected output

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a list of dates that both detection and pp reviewed are non-zero. In this case, try pd.merge(df, df1, how='inner', ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from how you merged your dataframes.
Try to do this like this:

```
DRG = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Dates', right_on='Date', how='outer')
```

You should maybe rename your columns as well, since one has `Date` and the other one `Dates`.
If the merge doesn't work as expected, try to convert you date to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime` and retry the merge.

Comment: Oh! I missed out on the different column names while I was typing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two dataframes before merger are df_A (the one with 'Dates' column) and df_B (the one with 'Date' column), try this:

```
DRG = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, how='outer', left_on='Dates', right_on='Date')
```

An Outer merge type is the use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join. This would be necessary in your case because it is possible for date(s) to exist in one dataframe that is/are not existent in the other.